# Excel VBA: How to remove/inject all nodes under specific XPath?

Tags: xml, parsing, vba, excel, xpath

I am having trouble implementing a loop which should remove all nodes below a XPath.
Once those nodes are deleted, another loop should inject nodes from a second document. So basically I want to replace old data within an already existing file with new data.

I think I got the basic framework covered, however, there still could be some problems with the XPath itself I guess. Also I couldn't get any method to remove childs working :(

It would be much appreciated if someone could push me in the right direction as I basically have no prior knowledge regarding XML parsing using VBA.

best regards,
daZza

Here's my code so far:

VBA:

```
Sub injectXML()

Dim sourceXML As DOMDocument60
Dim targetXML As DOMDocument60
Dim sourceNList As IXMLDOMNodeList 
Dim sourceNode As IXMLDOMNode
Dim targetNList As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim targetNode As IXMLDOMNode
Dim sourceAttributes As IXMLDOMNamedNodeMap
Dim targetAttributes As IXMLDOMNamedNodeMap

Set sourceXML = New DOMDocument60
sourceXML.Load ("C:\...\source.xml")

Set targetXML = New DOMDocument60
targetXML.Load ("C:\...\target.xml")

sourceXML.async = False
sourceXML.validateOnParse = False
targetXML.async = False
targetXML.validateOnParse = False

Set sourceNList = sourceXML.SelectNodes("//test/TLRule")
Set targetNList = targetXML.SelectNodes("//RuleCollection/TLRule/TLRule")


For Each targetNode In targetNList

    [remove the node]   

Next targetNode


For Each sourceNode In sourceNList

    [append all Data from source.xml to target.xml]  

Next sourceNode


sourceXML.Save ("C:\...\target.XML")

End Sub
```

source XML structure:

```
<test>
    <TLRule>
        <RuleCommand>
            <RuleID Value="0004" />
        </RuleCommand>
    </TLRule>
    <TLRule>
        <RuleCommand>
            <RuleID Value="0005" />
        </RuleCommand>
    </TLRule>
</test>
```

target XML structure:

```
<RuleCollection>
     <TLRule>

        [lots of other data in <TLRule> + child tags]

        <TLRule>
            <RuleCommand>
                <RuleID Value="0004" />
        <TLRule>
    <TLRule>
<RuleCollection>
```

**Edit:**

Thanks to Martin I was able to get done the first part of my macro (deleting all the old data).

```
Set targetNList = targetXML.SelectNodes("//RuleCollection/TLRule/TLRule/RuleCommand")
Set targetNListSubstitution =    targetXML.SelectNodes("//RuleCollection/TLRule/TLRule/RuleSubstitution")
Set targetNListCleanUp = targetXML.SelectNodes("//RuleCollection/TLRule/TLRule")


For Each Item In targetNList
    Item.ParentNode.RemoveChild (Item)
Next


For Each Item In targetNListSubstitution
    Item.ParentNode.RemoveChild (Item)
Next


For Each Item In targetNListCleanUp
    If Item.HasChildNodes = False Then Item.ParentNode.RemoveChild (Item)
Next
```

Now I 'just' need to inject all the data from my sourceXML / sourceNList.
This seems to be the hardest part of the task though, as it needs to be injected in the place where I deleted the old data using the above methods.

From my point of view I'd need some kind of anchor/pointer for that, but I just can't see how I would get one in there.

Maybe some of you can help? Would be much appreciated.

best regards,
daZza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
Set targetNList = targetXML.SelectNodes("//RuleCollection/TLRule/TLRule")


For Each targetNode In targetNList

    [remove the node]   

Next targetNode
```

can be implemented as

```
Set targetNList = targetXML.SelectNodes("//RuleCollection/TLRule/TLRule")

For Each item In targetNList
  item.parentNode.removeChild item
Next
```

As your paths `/RuleCollection/TLRule/TLRule/RuleCommand` and `//RuleCollection/TLRule/TLRule/RuleSubstitution` select child nodes of `//RuleCollection/TLRule/TLRule` it should suffice to run the `For Each` loop on `targetXML.SelectNodes("//RuleCollection/TLRule/TLRule")`.

As for inserting the nodes from the other document, I think you can use e.g.

```
Set target = targetXML.selectSingleNode("//RuleCollection/TLRule")
For Each sourceNode In sourceNList
  target.appendChild sourceNode
Next
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to work. I couldn't yet verify if it only deletes the data I want to be deleted or even more.

Even if it does, I guess I can figure out a solution by trial&error :)


Do you think I could use the same approach for injecting the data from the other file?

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestion. I managed to rewrite it so it fits my purpose perfectly now (see main post) :)

All that's left is injecting the source data now. You don't happen to have any suggestions on that do you?

best regards,
daZza

Comment: @daZza, I have edited my post with some insertion code. Also note that for deleting your stuff a single loop over `//RuleCollection/TLRule/TLRule` should suffice.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try soon.
A single loop deleted too much (there is much more data above the stuff I want to delete with TLRule tags) and changing the XPath left all the parent TLRule tags undeleted, so my xml file was "spammed" with empty <TLRule></TLRule> where I deleted the data. 

That's why I did that cleanup thing.